# Minifying bootstrap.js with connect-assetmanager causes syntax error. Why?

Tags: node.js, express, twitter-bootstrap, connect, minify

Using connect-assetmanager in a node.js/Express app.

This works:

```
  js: {
      dataType: 'javascript',
      path: __dirname + '/../public/javascript/',
      files: [//'jquery-1.7.1.js'
             'bootstrap.min.js'
      ],
      route: /\/static\/javascript\/script\.js/
  }
```

(Note using the already minimized version of boostrap.js, and commented out the jquery file for testing).

This fails:

```
  js: {
      dataType: 'javascript',
      path: __dirname + '/../public/javascript/',
      files: [//'jquery-1.7.1.js'
             'bootstrap.js'
      ],
      route: /\/static\/javascript\/script\.js/
  }
```

Note the non-minimized `bootstrap.js`.

The failure is in the browser (Chrome).  At line 120 in the connect-assetmanager compressed portion of bootstrap.js there's a syntax error:

```
119 isActive=$parent.hasClass('open')
120 clearMenus()!isActive&&$parent.toggleClass('open')
  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
121 return false}}
```

This is my first go at using something like connect-assetmanager to minify/concat static files.  Is this kind of thing typical with JS minifiers?  What do I do about this?

It's doubtful we will need to really debug into bootstrap.js on the client outside of prod anytime soon, but I don't want to invest in connect-assetmanager if corruption of Javascript is typical.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this really counts as an answer, but the newer versions of the Bootstrap fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You missed out the whole discussion on the missing semicolon issue with the bootstrap

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/3057